# how to make my json file trimmed and all lowercse in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, database, trim, lowercase

how to make my json file trimmed and all lowercse in nodejs. I have an excel with which I am making a json file by converting the excel to json. I need my json to be in lowercase and trimmed. I converted excel to json but my json is not in lowercase and trimmed

Comment: Do you want only the values to be trimmed and lowercase, or the keys as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform a text string into all lowercase letters using `.toLowerCase()` method:

```js
var str = 'HELLO WORLD';
var lowerCase = str.toLowerCase();

console.log('Uppercase string: ' + str);
console.log('Lowercase string: ' + lowerCase);
```

Comment: I don't know how to trim your file :(

Comment: I want to make my whole json file converted to lowercase

Comment: about code seems like only a string is being converted to lowercase